# Apache config, why it's always says The Requested operation has failed, I can not run apache?

Tags: php, mysql, apache-2.2

I'm already tired, I can not start apache, I'm reinstalled it a few times, but it doesn't work, was a different situations, such as firewall or whatever, but now I can not run apache ordinary cause it says "The requested operation has failed", I used cmd and there I've got errors:

```
F:\server\apache\Apache2\bin>apache
Syntax error on line 60 of F:/server/apache/Apache2/conf/httpd.conf:
Cannot load F:/server/apache/modules/mod_actions.so into server: \xcd\xe5 \xed\x
e0\xe9\xe4\xe5\xed \xf3\xea\xe0\xe7\xe0\xed\xed\xfb\xe9 \xec\xee\xe4\xf3\xeb\xfc
.

F:\server\apache\Apache2\bin>
```

if I comment line 60 the error will be in the next line, there is a module files and apache can not run them, I think it's all 'caz directories wrong, but which the same, everywhere I wrote right path?

Comment: and pls. dont tell me about xamp or others as you think "cool sh.." server pockets.

Comment: Do you have a little Apache icon in the system tray? You can run 'test configuration' from there that might give more info. Also, is the logs folder created?

Comment: yes, wait a lit bit

Comment: 57 # Example:
58 # LoadModule foo_module modules/mod_foo.so
59 #
60 LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
61 LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
62 LoadModule asis_module modules/mod_asis.so
63 LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
64 #LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so

Comment: sorry, I can't still mind how to insert it all not in one line.

Comment: Test Configuration says the same I'm already show you what was that I did in cmd.

Comment: here is error log:

Comment: @Tolan: You should add the additional infos to your question (not in comments which are much harder to read and not visible upfront).

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to load a Linux shared object (`mod_actions.so`) into a Windows version of Apache (which would use `.DLL` files).  You need to either find a compiled Windows DLL of mod_actions or download the source and compile it yourself.